# Android silent mode - is there a way for a notification to sound?

Tags: android, push-notification, alarm

#### Context

I am working on an app that uses FCM. The use of this application is to alert a user of an event that is occurring (such as an alarm system). In view of the ***alarm nature of the notification***, it is essential that a sound is played when receiving a notification **even if the smartphone is in *silent* or *vibrate* mode**.

---

#### Question

Is there a way to achieve this described behavior for all smartphone modes  *(silent, vibrate, sound)* ?

---

#### What I've tried

- As I am working with API26> I created a notification channel to have the highest priority which is *Max Priority*,
- I've set the notification channel to *bypass Do Not Disturb* mode like so:

  `notificationChannel.SetBypassDnd(true);`

  Obviously it only affects the Do Not Disturb mode and absolutely not what I want,
- In the notification builder, I've set the notification priority to *Max* and the category to *Alarm*:

  ```
  .SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityMax)
  .SetCategory(NotificationCompat.CategoryAlarm);
  ```

  Reading the Android documentation, this feature is also related to Do Not Disturb Mode.

I am actively looking for a solution to this problem, but at this point I'm a bit stuck.

---

#### Any suggestions ?

I've read about a [full screen intent](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#urgent-message) in the Android documentation but it's not written that a sound will fire if the smartphone is in silent mode.

Maybe there is a way to create a service that rings when the notification arrives? But this service has to be running all the time, which isn't really a good design idea.

If you guys have any idea, any remarks or suggestions, **i'd be grateful to read them !**

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15665116/4327305 they are using alarm stream

Comment: @philéas-lambert, check out the answer below 

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set priority for your notification.

```
    private fun setPriorityForAlarmNotification() {
    if (notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted) {
      notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY)
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        val policy = NotificationManager.Policy(PRIORITY_CATEGORY_ALARMS, 0, 0)
        notificationManager.notificationPolicy = policy
      }
    }
  }
```

As I can see you setCategory for your notification builder is NotificationCompat.CategoryAlarm.

However, in order to set this priority, you need this permission on your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

And request permission if needed

```
    fun requestNotificationPolicyPermission() {
    val notificationManager = activity!!.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    
    if (!notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted) {
      val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS)
      startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFICATION_POLICY)
    }
  }
```

This solution should work absolutely. Hope this can help you :D