# Mute audio on ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm using Google new MediaPlayer named ExoPlayer and cannot find a way to mute the sound

Is there an easy way to mute audio track on Google ExoPlayer ? Or changing volume ?

Comment: `player.volume = 0f`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

## Exoplayer 2.x.x

**Get the current volume:**
`int currentvolume = player.getVolume();`
**Mute:** `player.setVolume(0f);`
**Unmute:** `player.setVolume(currentVolume);`

---

## Exoplayer 1.x.x

I found two ways to achieve it by editing [`DemoPlayer`](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo/player/DemoPlayer.java#L308) from ExoPlayer.

#### Good one :

Basicly, you need to get the `audioTrackRenderer` which is a `ExoPlayerComponent` and send message to it. 
So :

1. Add `audioRenderer` member and set it in `onRenderers`:

   ```
   // Complete preparation.  
   this.videoRenderer = renderers[TYPE_VIDEO];  
   this.audioRenderer = renderers[TYPE_AUDIO];
   ```
2. Add public method :

   ```
   public void setMute(boolean toMute){
       if(toMute){
           player.sendMessage(audioRenderer, MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_VOLUME, 0f);
       } else {
           player.sendMessage(audioRenderer, MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_VOLUME, 1f);
       }
   }
   ```

**Usage :**
mute : `player.setMute(true);`
unmute : `player.setMute(false);`

#### The other one :

*This is not a good solution has the player will need to rebuffer when unmuting.*
Consist of changing the audio track to an empty one:

```
// mute
player.selectTrack(FullPlayer.TYPE_AUDIO, ExoPlayer.TRACK_DISABLED);

// Unmute
player.selectTrack(FullPlayer.TYPE_AUDIO, ExoPlayer.TRACK_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Great solution! I was using "selectTrack" way but the video stream rebuffed every time I selected different audio track.

Comment: In ExoPlayer 2.5 you can do the track selection solution. "In ExoPlayer 2.5 this rebuffering has been eliminated, allowing audio and text track selections to be made in a seamless way." https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/exoplayer-2-5-whats-new-b508c0ab606f

Comment: Is it possible for the ExoPlayer to play something at a volume that is independent from any system volume level?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I doubt that this is not an expected behavior for the User. As stated in the doc: `Android uses separate audio streams for playing music, alarms, notifications, the incoming call ringer, system sounds, in-call volume, and DTMF tones. This allows users to control the volume of each stream independently.`

Plus: 
`Unless your app is an alarm clock, you should play audio using the STREAM_MUSIC stream.`
Ref: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones

Comment: @HugoGresse Sometimes it's important to play a sound that the user will hear. I wanted to avoid changing global volume levels just for that.

Comment: probably worth another stackoverflow search like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071149/override-silent-mode-and-or-media-volume

Comment: There is a problem when an incoming call occurs, on some devices volume restores to default but ExoPlayer tells me volume is zero, which is false. https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3923

Answer (score 26):

The new way to mute and unmute volume as of version 2.X.X done as follows:

```
int currentvolume = player.getVolume();
```

make sure to call the line above after starting the player otherwise you will get a nullpointerexception

to mute volume:

```
player.setVolume(0f);
```

to unmute volume:

```
player.setVolume(currentVolume);
```

Comment: nice and simple!

Answer (score 10):

**Easily you can do it with ExoPlayer:**

**Java Code:**

```
float currentVolume = player.getVolume();
if (currentVolume == 0f) {
      player.setVolume(1f);
} else {
      player.setVolume(0f);
}
```

**Kotlin Code:**

```
val curentVol = player?.volume
if (curentVol == 0f) {
     player?.volume = 1f
} else {
     player?.volume = 0f
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**In ExoPlayer 2.x.x:**

**get the current volume:**

```
int currentVolume = player..getAudioComponent().getVolume();
```

**mute:**

```
player.getAudioComponent().setVolume(0f);
```

**unmute:**

```
player.getAudioComponent().setVolume(currentVolume);
```

Answer (score 4):

I will recommend get the current volume first and then mute it. When you will unmute you can give user same volume.

```
float currentvolume;
currentvolume = player.getVolume();
player.setVolume(0.0f);
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
player.setSelectedTrack(DemoPlayer.TYPE_AUDIO, DemoPlayer.TRACK_DISABLED);
```

analogous to [this line of code](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo/player/DemoPlayer.java#L202)

Comment: which is exactly the same as `player.selectTrack(FullPlayer.TYPE_AUDIO, -1);` with `ExoPlayer.TRACK_DEFAULT`. This is totaly not a good solution as unmuting the sound will have major delay

Comment: exactly the same but different. Anyway there are situations in which you want to completely disable the audio track (e.g. testing purpose)

Comment: it's exactly my second case in the accepted answer 'The other one"

Answer (score 2):

Just simply use player.setVolume(0) will silent the video.

Answer (score 1):

Returns the audio volume, with 0 being silence and 1 being unity gain (signal unchanged).

You should use new version: `implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.5'`

- Mute volume:

```kotlin
    exoPlayer.volume = 0f
```

- Unmute volume value:

```kotlin
    exoPlayer.volume = 1f
```

Answer (score 0):

Mute ExoPlayer using Kotlin

```
player.audioComponent?.volume = 0f
```