# How to design custom seekbar and volume control for ExoPlayer in Android

Tags: android, seekbar, exoplayer

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772985/how-can-i-design-the-custom-seekbar-in-android) and [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/) for Design Custom Seekbar for ExoPlayer but no luck.

I want to design custom thumb and ProgressBar for ExoPlayer. Following is the XML for ExoPlayer where I've tried to put seekbar but it's not coming as expected.

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer.AspectRatioFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/video_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surface_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/shutter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>
        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"/>

        <com.google.android.exoplayer.text.SubtitleLayout
            android:id="@+id/subtitles"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </com.google.android.exoplayer.AspectRatioFrameLayout>
```

One more question is how can I have custom volume controls for ExoPlayer like we have it in [MXPlayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=en) (vertical bar for volume).

#### Update

I have got the `SeekBar` using this method.

```
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) mediaController.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("mediacontroller_progress","id","android"));
seekBar.setThumb(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.player_thumb));
```

Now the only thing is to get vertical volume control like [MXPlayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad).

Comment: `Hop i 'll get answer ASAP.` answer for what? there is no "question" in your question...

Comment: @pskink One more question is that can I have Custom Volume Controls for ExoPlayer like we have it in MXPlayer (vertical bar for Volume). Now I've My Question in BOLD font.

Comment: MediaController is optionnal. You actually don't need it and you can write your own classes.

Answer (score 6):

[AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) is helpful for handling the system volume. I have implemented horizontal volume `Seekbar` to control audio volume with `ExoPlayer`. Just use this :

**Create AudioManager object :**

```
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

**Handle Volume up/down Hardware Button :**

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){
            volumeSeekBar.setProgress(audioManager.getStreamVolume(exoPlayer.getAudioStreamType()));
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
            volumeSeekBar.setProgress(audioManager.getStreamVolume(exoPlayer.getAudioStreamType()));
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
```

**Handle volume using Seekbar :**

```
volumeSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(exoPlayer.getAudioStreamType(), i, 0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but I've closed that project a year back. :)

Comment: It will help to other.

Comment: definitely bro :)

Answer (score 3):

I've created a solution which works (at least for me, anyway) and creates a vertical SeekBar. [Create Java class like this](http://hackskrieg.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/working-vertical-seekbar-for-android/)  Hope this will help you.

If I read the ExoPlayer source code correctly you have to keep references to the audioRenderers you use when preparing the ExoPlayer instance.

```
exoPlayer.prepare(audioRenderer);
```

To change volume you have to send the following message:

```
exoPlayer.sendMessage(audioRenderer, MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_VOLUME, 0.1f);
```

Comment: How can I Bind it with ExoPlayer volume?

Comment: Yes I've read it but there was sendMessage for Audio On and Mute. I'll Try this and let you know!

Comment: According to my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27404447/1377145) you can use the third parameter of `sendMessage` to pass the volume from `0.00f` to `1f`.