# How to detect whether video contains sound or not using exoplayer

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer2.x

I want to check if my video contains a sound or not. Based on that I want to add sound enable/disable functionality in my project.

Comment: check this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27404447/7022347). It might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can track the current tracks with Player#EventListener#OnTracksChanged and get the current ones with Player#getCurrentTrackGroups(). If you go through the track groups you can look for the type. If you additionally want to check if any of the audio tracks was selected, then Player#getCurrentTrackSelections() is the place to look at.

Comment: Player#getCurrentTrackGroups() return info about all formats which contains track has audio, video and text etc.